# need to update data in another sheet EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writting a code which have to take data from the form `sheet3` and transfer data to another sheet. With this part is everything OK. 
With the same click I'm also want that program look at the data in  the same form `sheet3`,  take `Item's ID` (it's in the column A) from each filled row and after that find matches in the `sheet1`(column C). Then the code find match it identify the row where the match is and make subtraction in cell (Column I) i.e. Take value from form `sheet3`. It's in the column 4.  Then in the `sheet1` --> row where the match is --> column I  make subtraction using this value from `sheet3`
I attached printscreen for clearness.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxEK.jpg)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Button4_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim y as Long
    Dim roww as Long
    Dim matchess as Integer
    Dim IDitem as Integer
    Dim myrange as Long

    'Calculate starting rows
    x = 15
    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With
    myrange = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("C:I")

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        Do While .Cells(x, 1) <> ""

            'The next line copies values to Sheet2
            Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & erow & ":Z" & erow).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Z" & x).Value

            'increment row counters
            x = x + 1
            erow = erow + 1
        Loop
    End With
    y = 15
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
       Do While Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(y, 1) <> ""
          matchess = Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(y, 1)
          IDitem = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(matchess, myrange, 4, False)
          roww = Application.Match(matches, myrange, 0)
          .cell(roww, 7).Value = .cell(roww, 7).Value - IDitem
         y = y + 1
         Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

I don't know why but the second part of code doesn't work.

Additional information: sheet3: Rows starts from 15, Items ID in the merge column A and B. Amount in the merge column "S, T, U";  sheet1: Items ID in the column C, stock in the column I;

Guys help me to correct the code

Comment: (a) Declare your variables.  (b) Use `Option Explicit` to ensure you do (a).  (c) You say "the second part of code doesn't work" but don't tell us what you mean - so I am guessing that you are getting a error 13 Type Mismatch on the `Set IDItem` line.  If so, remove `Set` from that statement - VLookup does not return an object, so it is inappropriate to set a variable to point to that (non-existent) object.

Comment: Not work means that after click doesn't show any error and nothing happened except transfering. The stock in the sheet1 does't decrease. I declare variables but as I said nothing happend.

Comment: (a) Your `Do While Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(x, 1) <> ""` statement is saying "don't do anything within this section" because, prior to reaching that statement, you have set x to a value which ensures that the cell in column A of row x is "".  (b) Can you please include in your question the bits of your code where you are declaring your variables (`myrange`, `matchess`, `matches`, `IDitem`, `roww` and any others that I have missed).

Comment: Refer to point (b) in my first comment.  Place an `Option Explicit` at the start of your code module then, when it tells you that you haven't declared the variable `matches`, fix it, then tell me whether there is still an error and, if so, on which line.

Comment: Error 13 starts from myrange. I think the problem on the end with roww = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(matches, myrange, False)
          .cell(roww, 7).Value = .cell(roww, 7).Value - IDitem

Comment: If you have included `Option Explicit` (to force you to declare variables), and you have declared the variable `matches`, the next question is ... have you assigned a value to `matches` anywhere?  If not, it will probably still be `Empty` or `Nothing` or `0` or `""` (depending on what type you declared it as) - and `Empty` and `Nothing` are both likely to cause an error when you try to use them as the criteria for your match.  (P.S.  I have to go out now - I will be back online in about 3 to 4 hours time.)

Comment: Error 13 starts from myrange now but I think the problem on the end with 'roww ' and '.cells(roww,7)...' I think function match not give row number on 'sheet 1' so  '.cells' row not work. I don't think that declare variables make sense, because transfer function worked perfectly without declaration variables.

Comment: I will start from begining. Firstly the function looks in the `sheet3` It starts from row 15 and ends then the row is emty. `Do While Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(y, 1) <> ""` So function every time take value from first column and use it in next functions. With this value function looks in the `sheet1` column 3, matches. When it finds, function should identify row number and put it in `.cells(rowNo, 7)`.

Comment: So we  get cell adress. Line `IDitem = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(matchess, myrange, 4, False)` take value from sheet3 column 4 (it's amount that I sell) and the last function using the cell's adress in the `sheet1`and a value from `sheet3` (amount) make subtraction in that   cell. After that the fuction starts from the begining, but now it check second row (row -16). So responding you message value is assigned `y=15` and each time its' changing `Cells(y, 1)`

Comment: At the moment, your code does not run - it gives a `Compile error: Variable not defined` error and highlights the undeclared variable `matches`.  As I said in an earlier comment "Place an Option Explicit at the start of your code module then, when it tells you that you haven't declared the variable matches, **fix it, then tell me whether there is still an error and, if so, on which line**."  Until you fix that variable (which will cause `roww` not to be set, or set incorrectly) there is not much else I can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the `.Find` method in the past to handle problems like this. I have included an explanation of the loop in the code, but I'm happy to elaborate if you need.

```
Sub Find_Method()

    Dim LastRow_1 As Long
    Dim LastRow_3 As Long

    Dim Source_Item_ID_Range As Range
    Dim Search_Item_ID_Range As Range
    Dim Item_ID_Found_Cell As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    LastRow_1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow_3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Search_Item_ID_Range = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & LastRow_1)
    Set Source_Item_ID_Range = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A15:A" & LastRow_3)

    'For each Item ID cell in Sheet3, search for its
    'string in the Item ID column of Sheet1. If a match
    'is found, deduct 1 from the Warehouse Stock column
    'and move on to the next cell.

    For Each Cell In Source_Item_ID_Range

        Set Item_ID_Found_Cell = Search_Item_ID_Range.Find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Item_ID_Found_Cell Is Nothing Then

            Item_ID_Found_Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Item_ID_Found_Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value - Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value

        End If

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks MJV. This code already is somewhere about. But havesome issues. I don't know why but in the ' sheet '

Comment: Thanks MJV. This code  is already somewhere about. But have some issues. I don't know why but in the `sheet1` on the first empty row, column 6 after clicking code writes some negative number (for example I got -34). I fink it's some calculations but doesn't catch of what and a second one. Now I need to add some variables that formula    deduct not by 1, but take value from sheet3 column 4 and make arithmetical operation in sheet1 i.e. `Item_ID_Found_Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value` - `*****.Value`. I tried to do that but get error. Can you help me with that issue and how should look code finaly.

Comment: I have altered the code so that the value in column 4 of Sheet 3 is deducted from Sheet 1, instead of 1.

Comment: As for your first problem, there is an issue with your source and search ranges. I have tested it with my own data and there is no such problem. I would suggest converting both your ranges to tables, and referring directly to dynamic named ranges, that way you can avoid using 'last row' variables altogether. Also, just a reminder that once the solution is working, please accept the answer, and as a courtesy you should upvote any useful comments that @YowE3K has taken the time to provide you with.